# schedule python script through crontab

Tags: python, unix, cron

I am trying to add a python script to crontab with following lines:

```
0 * * * * /pathtoexecutable/file.py
0 0 1 * 1 /pathtoexecutable/file2.py
```

Files are executable python scripts.

`file.py` further initiates around 15 subprocesses, which store info in a MySQL database.

`file2.py` gets, obviously, executed though through crontab as well.

For some reason `file.py` isn't working via crontab, but if I run it through command line it works.

Comment: Have you activated logging in cron? What is in the log?

Answer (score 1):

1) Catch the output & errors of yours scripts :.

```
0 * * * * /pathtoexecutable/file.py &>> /path/some/log.txt
0 0 1 * 1 /pathtoexecutable/file2.py &>> /path/some/log2.txt
```

2) Be sure that every python file begins with a shebang : #! /usr/bin/env python

3) Be sure too that every python file has a exec mode (chmod +x file.py)

Comment: got nothing in logs.. they are blank you were missing >> in between i guess..
tried through both 2>&1 >> /path/some/log
and 2>&1 /path/some/log

Got nothing in them
the python files begin with a shebang.. I can execute them from commandline without explicitly specifying the interpreter

They have 777 permissions

Comment: No problem, Zahsas. I got it working now, I don't get it though..
modified command to include interpreter as well.. The scripts contain shebang but still they dont execute directly from cron. They work by specifying interpreter in /usr/local/bin.
Thanks for your time. Appreciated!